# Understanding the thread safety of a List<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

1. I am trying to understand why it prints Item 0, Item 0 and Item 1
2. In debugging it prints Item 0, Item 0, Item 1, Item 1

Above bullet in 2 result make sense. Can someone help me understand why it prints bullet in 1?

Taken from C# 9.0 in a Nutshell

```
class ThreadSafe
{
    static List<string> _list = new List<string>();

    public static void AddItem()
    {
        // lock the list
        lock (_list)
        {
            _list.Add("Item " + _list.Count);
        }
        // Rather than locking for the duration; copy to an array
        string[] items;
        lock (_list)
        {
            items = _list.ToArray();
        }
        foreach (string s in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
     }
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       new Thread(ThreadSafe.AddItem).Start();
       new Thread(ThreadSafe.AddItem).Start();
     }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the output depend on the speed and scheduling of the computer running your threads?

Comment: I only see one instance of "Item 1" https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oHjcz Does the code make sense if you include the thread number in the print?

Comment: Can you please clarify what part of output you expect to be different and why? Maybe you expect all separate calls to `Console.WriteLine` to be executed in one go? (@gunr2171's suggestion to add thread number to all print statements could help you to clarify what you asking or maybe even answer altogether)

Comment: using ThreadID, I can see first thread prints Item 0, then second thread prints Item 0. then second thread prints Item 1, and finishes the execution.  I am trying to understand why second thread prints Item 0, after first thread executes. Seems like it's doing concurrently.

Comment: Honestly this example in Joseph Albahari's book is not very good. The produced output is confusing. I hope they'll improve it, in the next version of their book!

Comment: So thread 1 added item to the list, now list contains "Item 0". Then it goes and prints the list, it has only one item - "Item 0". Then thread 1 goes and adds item to the list. List now contains two elements: "Item 0" (added by first thread) and "Item 1". It then prints them both, resuling in "Item 0", "Item 0", "Item 1".

Comment: Thanks @Evk. Now it makes sense to me.

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

> While a lock is held, the thread that holds the lock can again acquire and release the lock. Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released.

It will really depend on the environment but the straight forward answer is as follows.

1. Thread 1 will lock list.
2. Thread 2 will try to access but can't so it will wait
3. Thread 1 will add to the list
4. Thread 2 is still waiting
5. Thread 1 will release the lock
6. Thread 2 will lock the list
7. Thread 1 will try to lock the list but it is already locked so it will wait
8. Etcetera

It really depends on when the threads actually start computing. But this will be the most logical answer to the output that you are seeing. Running it on a different environment (CPU, etc) might result in different output.